# Pycharm runserver error with custom settings.py files

Tags: django, pycharm

just started using pycharm on a existing project, and having difficulty using the run/debug configurations in order to run the test server. The issue stems from their being no settings.py module as standard in django projects. Instead there is settings_base.py and then two different settings modules (settings_live.py and settings_test.py) that extend it by using 'from settings_base import *'. This causes manage.py to fail when running runserver because it can't find settings.py.

In the Django Support settings I have set the project root, and set Settings to settings_test.py however this has not helped. In the Django server run configuration I have setup I also have...

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings_test
```

... in the Environment Variables section. However when I use runserver it still says

```
Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing '/home/pete/Projects/the_project/manage.py'. It appears you've customized things.
You'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.
(If the file settings.py does indeed exist, it's causing an ImportError somehow.)
```

I tried wrapping the entire settings_test.py module in a try/except to see if it really was an import error, however it did not seem to work. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try adding `--settings=settings_test` to the "Additional options" in your PyCharm Run configuration and make sure that "Working directory" points to correct path.

Comment: I tried this but did not get any further. I just tried renaming settings_test.py to settings.py, and setting the appropriate file again in the Django Support/Run Config areas, and it worked this time. So I am very confused.

Comment: And all of a sudden, I change it back to settings_test and it works just fine. Who knows! Thanks anyway